# Permutation of pandas series with all elements in it (itertools)

Tags: python, pandas, permutation, python-itertools

I trying to get a back a series (or data frame) with permutations of the elements in that list:

```
stmt_stream_ticker = ("SELECT * FROM ticker;")
ticker = pd.read_sql(stmt_stream_ticker, eng)
```

which gives me my ticker series

```
    ticker
0   ALJ
1   ALDW
2   BP
3   BPT
```

then via function I'd like to work my list:

```
def permus_maker(x):

    global i # I tried nonlocal i but this gives me: nonbinding error
    permus = itertools.permutations(x, 2)
    permus_pairs = []

    for i in permus:
        permus_pairs.append(i)

    return permus_pairs.append(i)

test = permus_maker(ticker)

print(test)
```

This gives me 'None' back. Any idea what I do wrong?

edit1:

I tested user defined function vs integrated function (%timeit): it takes 5x as long.

Comment: `list.append()` returns None, return `permus_pairs` instead of `permus_pairs.append(i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list.append()` returns None, so return `permus_pairs` instead of `permus_pairs.append(i)`

Demo:

```
In [126]: [0].append(1) is None
Out[126]: True
```

but you don't really need that function:

```
In [124]: list(permutations(ticker.ticker, 2))
Out[124]:
[('ALJ', 'ALDW'),
 ('ALJ', 'BP'),
 ('ALJ', 'BPT'),
 ('ALDW', 'ALJ'),
 ('ALDW', 'BP'),
 ('ALDW', 'BPT'),
 ('BP', 'ALJ'),
 ('BP', 'ALDW'),
 ('BP', 'BPT'),
 ('BPT', 'ALJ'),
 ('BPT', 'ALDW'),
 ('BPT', 'BP')]
```

Be aware - if you are working with huge lists/Series/DataFrames, then it would make sense to use permutations iterator *iteratively* instead of exploding it in memory:

```
for pair in permutations(ticker.ticker, 2):
     # process pair of tickers here ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer, MaxU. I have read that lists are very "heavy" and I should avoid them. Can you advise how to best proceed?

Comment: That's true if you are going to operate with huge lists/series/DFs... I gave you this answer, because you were collecting a list in your function and returning it back - so my answer won't use more memory compared to yours. In order to give you a memory saving version - I need to know how are you going to use those permutations...

Comment: Thank you, MaxU. In fact, I have another data frame with prices of the respective stocks, i.e. BP. For instance, the list above will be used to call time series from other data frames; the actual permutation list has n=58, larger but not too large I would say.